# C#: Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, arrays, wcf, for-loop, nullreferenceexception

```
public Person[] GetColleagues(String fn, String ln)
{
    string[] data1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"link1")
    string[] personv = data1[0].Split('$');
    string[] data2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"link2");
    string[] jobv = data2[0].Split('$');

    string[] jobsearch = Array.FindAll(jobv, element => element.Contains(GetJobInfo(fn, ln).companyName));

     if (jobsearch.Length>0)
     {
         string[] colleagues = new string[jobsearch.Length];

         for (int n = 0; n < jobsearch.Length - 1; n++)
         {
             String[] pn = new String[jobsearch.Length];
             string[] detail = jobsearch[n].Split('#');

             pn[n] = detail[0];

             colleagues[n] = Array.Find(personv, element => element.EndsWith(pn[n]));}   

             Person[] instances = new Person[colleagues.Length];

             for (int i = 0; i < colleagues.Length-1; i++)
             {
                 string[] test = colleagues[i].Split('#');

                 instances[i].firstName = test[0];
                 instances[i].lastName = test[1];
                 instances[i].dateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(test[2]);
                 instances[i].email = test[3];
                 instances[i].streetAddress = test[4];
                 instances[i].suburb = test[5];
                 instances[i].state = test[6];
                 instances[i].postcode = Convert.ToInt32(test[7]);
                 instances[i].job.positionNumber = Convert.ToInt32(test[8]);
                 instances[i].job.positionTitle = helpmethod(test[8])[1];
                 instances[i].job.positionDescription = helpmethod(test[8])[1];
                 instances[i].job.companyName = helpmethod(test[8])[1];
             }
             return instances;
         }
         return null;
}

public String[] helpmethod(string num)
{
    string[] data2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"link2");
    string[] jobv = data2[0].Split('$');
    string searchjob = Array.Find(jobv, element => element.StartsWith(num, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    string[] resultjob = searchjob.Split('#');

    return resultjob;
}
```

**I always got a null reference exception null error on** `instances[i].firstName`,`instances[i].lastName` ... 
**even i change** `instances[i].firstName = test[0];` to `instances[i].firstName = "tony";`
**still get null reference exception error.**

**Here is Custom my person class and job class**

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public String firstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String lastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String email { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String streetAddress { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String suburb { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String state { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int postcode { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Job job { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Job
{
    [DataMember]
    public String companyName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int positionNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String positionTitle { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String positionDescription { get; set; }

}
```

**Here is my txt file**

For link1

```
$abc#ko#18/07/1959#abc@gmail.com#unit 90,25 thor Street#unknow#Queensland#4109#0$Efg#Ans#9/11/1990#tt.y@gmail.com#223 Anson Rd#ChinaTown#Boston#4188#1$Catherine#Ong#05/05/1993#cth.ong@gmail.com#osh Street#Melbourne#Vic#2008#2$Kelvin#Ong#04/05/1983#k.ong@gmail.com#ash Street#hello#qld#4308#3$Amy#Goh#01/01/1987#a.goh@gmail.com#lol Street#hey#qld#4108#4$Henry#Li#06/06/1988#h.li@gmail.com#lucky Street#Chiantown#qld#4118#5
```

For link2

```
$0#Boss#God of this company#hi Technology Pte Ltd$1#Engineer#Engineer Leader#ABC Pte Ltd$2#Secretary#assist boss#hi Technology Pte Ltd$3#AssistEngineer#assist Engineer#hi Technology Pte Ltd$4#Cleaner#cleanning work#hi Technology Pte Ltd$5#CEO#Boss of this company#ABC Pte Ltd
```

Comment: maybe `instances[i]` is `null`, have you tried debugging?

Comment: @wudzik instances is a new created array base on type person,yes, it is null, because i want put in something...

Comment: so firsty initialize it like: `instances[i]=new Person()`

Comment: @wudzik it works...seems i make a basic mistake

Comment: @wudzik but i having another problem on the received items, always have a null items followed...is that casued by split array?

Comment: What is `received` items?

Comment: soleved by change 'for (int n = 0; n < jobsearch.Length-1; n++)' to 'for (int n = 0; n < jobsearch.Length; n++)'

Comment: @wudzik it been resolved, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize `instances[i]`:

```
    instances[i] = new Person();        
    instances[i].job = new Job();
    instances[i].firstName = test[0];
```

Comment: `instances[i] = new Person();` not .firstName ;)

Comment: @wudzik: first names are people too!

Answer (score 3):

You declare the array like this:

```
Person[] instances = new Person[colleagues.Length];
```

But you'll see that each element in the array is still `null` at that point. You'll have to create a new instance of `Person` for each element:

```
for (int i = 0; i < colleagues.Length-1; i++)
{
    string[] test = colleagues[i].Split('#');
    instances[i] = new Person();
    instances[i].firstName = test[0];
```